# "Max Memory" Error when scrolling

Tags: error

I'm having this really weird issue with Vim, when I scroll down certain files it gives me a "Max memory" error and then the entire file turns white. It doesn't make any sense though because the file I view is <500 SLOC and is a .yaml file. Here's my .vimrc

```
call plug#begin()
  Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
  Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
  Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production' } 
  Plug 'thaerkh/vim-workspace'
call plug#end()

let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"

set anti enc=utf-8
set guifont=Monaco:h14

au VimEnter * NERDTree

set autoindent 
set relativenumber
set number
set mouse=a
```

Original error:
[image]

After running the file as `nvim --clean`

[image]

Also noticed this line:
[image]

next I ran it using `vim --clean`, same errors, different colors :)

[image]

Also, I noticed at the bottom of my file there is a large blob of data:

```
genesis: 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...
```

[image]

After inspection it looks like a ton of text on a single line. Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: What if you disable the plugins and in particular `polyglot`?

Comment: Please [edit] with a minimal vimrc that solves the problem ([How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604))

Comment: @D.BenKnoble removed comments to make it shorter

Comment: Thanks for the simplifications :-) But I would like you to try to simplify further :-/ Do you the problem if you disable NerdTree? Do you have the problem if you disable Polyglot? What we would need is the absolute minimal config :-) To reproduce the problem we would also need your text if that is possible :-/

Comment: try `vim --clean`. Also, what exactly do you mean with `certain files`? What exact file types provoke that behaviour?

Comment: its a .yaml file, nothing crazy @ChristianBrabandt. was scrolling down using mouse when it happened

Comment: I think I found the problem here, it's due to a bunch of data on a single line. Any way for me to avoid this problem in the future, under the assumption I will deal with similar files?

Comment: ah, `yaml` is notoriously known for some crazy patterns. You could try to increase the 'maxmempattern' option value (not sure this will work) or you may want to try to lower the 'synmaxcol' setting to say 250 or so.

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10730

Comment: Is there a way to just avoid synax highlighting for super long lines, but keep it for everything else? Mainly annoyed that the file turns completely white after passing this line. @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: isn't that exactly what 'synmaxcol' does? Avoid syntax highlighting for lines longer than this amount of columns?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt it seems so, but max memory is still reached firrst and I have to exit the full screen error